# Go to Definition (F12) not taking you to the correct line in Visual Studio for C/C++ code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, macros, project, definition

I work in the Visual Studio IDE. I inhered some C code where a lot of macros are defined: it's like a cascade of macros are referring to some other replacement, again referring to some other replacement.

However when I press F12 (See/Go to Definition) on one of these "variables" (I don't know how to call them), I end up in the right file, but on the wrong line. Any idea how to fix this?

Below some example:

So *f* is a pointer of type Fichiers that stores the memory address of an instance of class Fichiers, namely *Fichiers* (which is an object).

```
Name    Value   Type
_f_->input.produit_1[0].actu.desc_prod.c_tarif  70  int
```

Some relevant pieces of code

```
#define _f_NUMERO_TT            (_f_PARM_PROD.actu.desc_prod.num_TT) // _f_->input.produit_1[0].actu.desc_prod.num_TT

#define _f_PARM_PROD    (_f_INPUTS.produit_1[PACKAGE_PRODUIT_BASE]) 

    struct Inputs
    {
#define _f_INPUTS  (_f_->input)

        struct ParametersInputs
        {
#define _f_PARAMETERS   (_f_INPUTS.parameter) //_f_->input.parameter

            DATE date_fichiers;
            DATE date_fichiers_pp;
...
So instead of pasting "_f_NUMERO_TT" I need to replace it everywhere with
_f_->input.produit_1[0].actu.desc_prod.num_TT
```

Comment: The best way to fix this would be to roll up one's sleeves and learn how to work with C++ code the old-fashioned way: without depending on various crutches from glorified IDEs, just a plain text editor. This quickly forces one to get in the habit of organizing their code in an orderly, structured fashion. It's never a mystery where some particular function's definition is. One quickly picks up effective text editing and searching skills, to locate hard to find code. Over time, mental acuity and focus increases. There's no other choice: otherwise one gets hopelessly lost in a mountain of code.

Comment: "it's like a cascade of macros" we mere mortals normally want to get rid of cascades of macros, not navigate them.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I know, that's my other question on here, but for now, I want to navigate them :).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: thx for your suggestion, but I inherited the mountain of code so... I will have to deal with it.

Comment: Yes you do. By doing what I suggested. Not relying on a text editor to do the dirty work. A C or a C++ compiler is required in in order to fully interpret complex macros or high level C++ constructs. Because that's what C or C++ compiler's sole reason for existence is. A text editor is not a C++ compiler. All that a text editor can do, in response to a function key, is perform a rudimentary search. Some text editors integrate with a compiler engine, to get better results and insight. If yours doesn't, there's nothing that can be done about it.

Comment: If you press F12 while the cursor is on a macro name, you are taken to the corresponding #define line, because that's where that name is defined. Do you want to go to the place where a real variable which results from the macro expansion is defined? I don't know of any IDE that does this. So just get rid of the macro and call it done.

Comment: Rebuild the Intellisense index (see Google).  It breaks *all the time*

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Time to move into the 21st century? <ducks>  There's nothing about using an IDE that stops you writing good code.

Comment: Inherited a mountain of shitty, macro-infested code, once. Worked on it for a few weeks while I lined up a new job.

Comment: Mind you, that was also a new job. If the first code they give the new guy looks like garbage, I couldn't trust that the rest of the code base wouldn't be a trainwreck. There's a lot to be said for following a fail fast strategy when in a good hiring market.

Comment: I like the 21st century, @PaulSanders, except for the problem is that there are too many people who get distracted by all the shiny toys and don't learn the skills needed to build those shiny toys and make them work. When there were no shiny toys that bring everything forward, on a silver platter, one had no alternative to learning how to fish without a rod that catches the fish all by itself. Now, too often a conclusion is reached that there's no reason to learn how to fish, the rod will catch it all by itself. Except that when the rod breaks, you have nothing for dinner.

Comment: Much truth in that, @sam.  The new toys are great, if you use them properly, and seductive if you don't.

Comment: Reminders me of a story I read years ago, @PaulSanders. Apparently, at least at some point, VS used an internally-generated `Makefile` to run its own compiler. Everything was behind the UI but there was a `Makefile` that the UI iteratively patched, as things got created and deleted. Some lost soul was complaining that VS was spewing crazy errors instead of building. Completely lost, the sad soul was a fish out of water. The Linux guy said -- hey, this looks familiar. Poked around, pulled up the Makefile in Notepad, fixed it, and the code compiled. Awe and reverence followed...

Comment: You can try cleaning and rebuilding everything, manually delete everything in your output folders, and remove the hidden ".vs" folder in your project, but I've been using VS since the earliest version (don't recall when Intellisense first came about though), and have yet to encounter any version where this isn't a regular problem (has improved over the years though)

Comment: @user4581301 Thx for the tip :). I'm not in the C++ hiring market though, I just ended up in a place they have (apparently rather old/shitty) code in SQL/SAS and C/C++ . Not sure why they did not hire a professional C++ developer instead of me. Guess they wanted someone who understands the economic/math part behind it (although that's not even very necessary imho).

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI m. could be an AI : it now does not take me to the #define line, have to rebuild the Intellisense index apparently. Thx Paul Sanders!

Comment: One of the neatest Visual Basic programs I ever saw was written by a lady in marketing. It worked beautifully, but any changes to it, they wanted multi-threading to support extra simultaneous sensors, over a 4800 baud serial bus, would have required a complete re-write. Wish she was still with the company. He probably could have explained better why what management wanted was insane (read data into database, read database from VB in a single thread) because I could see from the unused hooks that's where she'd been headed. You don't need to be a professional. You just need to think like one.

Comment: @sam _Reminds me of a story I read years ago_ I'm delighted to be able to say that's never happened to me.  VS's build system seems pretty robust these days (unlike, say, Xcode, for example...).  You do have to (or it helps to) hand-edit the project file sometimes though, that's a handy skill to have.  These are 'XML-like', in case you've never delved.